# im stuck with firebase authetication

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, authentication, gradle

i was trying to connect firebase into my flutter project, after tons of research, im still dont know the bug.im trying to connect authentication, follow the tutorial step by step, but it doesn't seems like gonna work

somebody please help me :V, im only had 1.5 month anymore. (btw, i dont know how to post the right version if stackoverflow, im so sorry)

here, written in the console

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Flutter_Project\firebase_authentication\android\build.gradle' line: 25
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method setVariantDir() for arguments [debug] on task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' of type com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

and this problem show up

(-) Cannot resolve symbol 'Properties'
(-) throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")

and this is the code of build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'   // this is line 25
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.firebase_authentication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.0')

    // Add the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
    // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'

    // Add the dependencies for any other desired Firebase products
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries
}
```

please, kind people

Answer (score 0):

Try to flutter clean first it seems the machine cannot find your flutter.sdk

Have you put the file from firebase google-services.json to the folder android/app folder?

And also add the depedencies for firebase ? on file build.grandle but **not** inside android/app folder

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
}
}
```